# Querying on the stored procedure result set

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Im using SQL Server 2008. I have a result set from the stored procedure and i want to fire some more queries on the result set for e.g order by desc /asc and some querying. So what is the best way to do it. Using views or by using OPENQUERY.
Please help.

Comment: See [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) and similar questions have been asked many times already on this site

Answer (score 0):

You can save results of stored procedure calls in any table or table variable that has same number and type of fields as the result set returned by the stored procedure, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #temp(col1, col2)
EXEC usp_Proc1(@param1)

SELECT  *
FROM    #temp
```

Condition is that `usp_Proc1` returns rows consisting of columns of type `INT` and `VARCHAR(10)` (in that order).